# Asp.Net Handler Response Redirect

Tags: asp.net, redirect, handler

I use ajax from Aspx page thats why I use handler.In my handler I use my helper class. I try to redirect in class if user session is timeout but I cant here is my code ,

```
  string url;
        try
        {
            url = HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode(HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["URL"]);
        }
        catch
        {
            url = "";
        }
        string u = Yaz.WebForms.Configuration.FrSettings.Settings.AppVirtualPath + "Default.aspx?ReturnUrl=" + url;
        string s = HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.ToString());
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(u + "?" + s);
```

My ajax code :

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            url: '../ashx/GetFileProperties.ashx',
```

The problem is my HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["URL"] give me handler link but I need the page link for going back to the page after login.

How can I get the link of the page(aspx) in my class ?